# How to select query in oracle from 2 different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created 2 tables as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE emp_bio(name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ,id NUMBER, DOB DATE,PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE emp_sal(id NUMBER REFERENCES emp_bio(id), salary NUMBER,PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Now, when I query as,

```
SELECT emp_sal.salary,emp_bio.name
FROM emp_sal right join emp_bio on emp_sal.id=emp_sal;
```

I get duplicate values in the output. Can anyone help me to remove that duplicate values !? Thank you.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a `JOIN` on both tables using both tables' `id` columns, since they're the ones relating both tables:

```
SELECT
    eb.name,
    es.salary
FROM emp_bio AS eb
INNER JOIN emp_sal AS es
    ON es.id = eb.id
```

Comment: Thank you @Felix Pamittan , it worked :)
But can you xplain what is eb and es here ? and what does inner join do !?

Comment: `eb` and `es` are table aliases. It'll increase the readability of your code so you don't have to type the whole table name again and again.

Comment: See `eb` right after `emp_bio` in the `FROM` clause? That's how you assign them. You could put the keyword `AS` also to avoid confusion. I suggest you read on the basics of SQL first. You'll learn a lot more than just asking straight here.

Comment: If this is Oracle, the query will not compile (which means the OP marked it correct without testing it - bravo, Shree!) In oracle table aliases must be given right after the table name, without the word AS. (AS can be used, optionally, for column aliases.) In addition, the OP wanted an outer join, since perhaps not all employees appear in the salary table - why change from outer to inner join?

Comment: @ShreeNaath - are you sure "it worked"? That is not possible, since the syntax is incorrect, so how do you define "it worked"?

Comment: @mathguy , Pamittan added 'as' into the query for me to understand. The query'll work fynn without 'as' ..